# Contents of the line rmarkdown unformatted latex pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, kable, kableextra

I need to wrap the contents of the line marked in red. The content of this row is too large. the output of this content is in pdf

````
```{r tabela1, echo=FALSE, include=F, fig.pos='H'}

tabela1  = kableExtra::kbl (tabela1,
                             caption = "Ficha de verificação de procedimentos de coleta",
                             booktabs = T,
                             longtable = T,
                             align = "c")%>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 10, latex_options = c("repeat_header", "HOLD_position"), position = "center")%>%
  column_spec (1, width = "15cm",  bold = T)%>%
  column_spec (2, bold = T)
  
```

`r tabela1`
````

How to break the content of that line?

[image: see image]

Comment: no image was shared

Comment: kableExtra is just showing the data you put in tabela1. Probably there's a way to break up the details of the location before assigning it. Maybe you'll want separate lines for latitude, longitude, etc.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible: include the output of `dput(tabela1)` into the question.

Comment: my output is according to the shared image

Comment: Hi Francisco, have a look at this [blog entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)